# json_script and concatenate variable name

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I need to concatenate the variable name from a template variable and hand it to the `json_script` template tag.
I tried:

```
{% with sensorname|add:"-data" as SensorNameData %}
    {{ values|json_script:SensorNameData }}    
    output: {{ SensorNameData }}
{% endwith %}
```

Which did not work, so I created a `filter` templatetag:

```
@register.filter
def combined(str1, str2):
    return f"""{str1}{str2}"""
```

and tried:

```
    {{ values|json_script:sensorname|combined:"-data" }}
```

but when applying it, I end up with the parsed list of values and then `-data`. Can I somehow tell the template processor to validate `sensorname` first and then `values|json_script:xxx`?

Comment: You don't apply the filter on the `sensorname`, but on the result of the `values|json_script:sensorname`

Comment: But defining custom template filters, etc. often is a bad idea. Usually that means you need to shift part of the logic to the view.

Comment: I have buttons that fetch data to display them in a chart, and I need to know which data was fetched for a chart, so HTMX plugs it in the right place and also deletes the correct object when being closed.